# Use two lists to check if one list contains non-duplicate elements

Tags: python, list

I made a memory game in python where players take turn picking two tiles in a grid to see if the revealed letters match.

I used two lists for this, one to store the letters e.g. `letters = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']` and the other to record the revealed letters that matches so far in the game e.g. `correctly_revealed = ['A', 'A', ' ', ' ']` and then use an `if letters == correctly_revealed` condition to end the game. The letters only get revealed if both letters in chosen tiles matches.

The letters do not always come in pairs however, meaning that the remaining unrevealed letters all be different letters e.g. `letters = ['B', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and `correctly_revealed = ['B', 'B', ' ', ' ']`. So I'm not sure how to set an `if` condition to end the game if it comes to that point

Comment: have you tried doing something like: if the number of elements which have 'A' in list1 are equal to the number of elements in which have 'A' in list2 then end game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand, but it sounds like you could just keep track of the total number of matches (in your example, there's 2), then when `num_matches == 2` you have your game complete state.

Of course, you'll have to make sure you count correct matches properly.

Answer (score 0):

If both lists are going to have same element on same index then checking for **letters == revealed** will work fine but if the index is different then use

```
for i in revealed:
    letters.remove(i)
if not letters:
    end_game_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check two lists in python by following this code :

```
import functools

if functools.reduce(lambda x, y : x and y, map(lambda p, q: p == q,letters,correctly_revealed), True):
   #finish the game or any logic you want 
   pass
```